# User friendly CLI for git

Tags: git, command-line

I'm looking for something that wraps git by providing an easy and consistent [command-line interface (CLI)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) while fulfilling the following:

- the CLI should use consistently the same names for the same things, i.e. not interchanging words like `index`, `cache`, `stage` or `staging area`.
- fix some weird anomalies in the interface, like `log` and `diff` interpreting the refs passed as arguments differently.
- not necessarily be backward compatible, we have the native CLI for that (similar to apt vs apt-get)

Does something like this already exist?

Comment: If your question was answered to your satisfaction, you can accept an answer by clicking on the check mark under the voting arrows.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that you could try, but may not like or may love, is using [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/), (hg), as a git client via the [hg-git plug in](http://hg-git.github.io/).

Mercurial tends to be much more consistent and user friendly than git, (in my personal opinion).

Answer (score 0):

Try [Easy Git](https://people.gnome.org/~newren/eg/), which is meant to be a newbie-friendly interface to Git, or the four similar projects linked to at the bottom of that page.